# How do I add a new floor in Gnomoria?

Tags: gnomoria

I'm trying to add a new floor in Gnomoria.  I removed a clay for (before realizing that there was a replace command).  Looking at the wiki under [Construction Strategies](http://www.gnomoriawiki.com/wiki/Construction_Strategies) I saw that there is supposed to be a way to add new floors (Terrain_Floors).  However, I don't see this under my list of terrain build options.

Is the wiki correct, and am I just missing something?  Also, is there any way to just add a new floor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Finally found it!  What threw me off is that the floor is not in the terrain menu.  Instead you can add a floor by starting at the base menu as follows:

Build -> Terrain -> Floor